# If one presidential term is four years, how do you say two terms in terms of years? Two four years's?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

If one presidential term is four years, how do you say two terms in terms of years? Two four years's? Two four years doesn't make a lot of sense but two four years's sounds weird.

Comment: Two four-year terms.

Comment: What if you don't wanna use the word "term?" What if you just wanna say it in years?

Comment: Then it's just "Eight years".

Answer (score 0):

You can use an adverb to qualify the 'four'.

In Britain we could say: Twice four years

In America that would be: Two times four years

Comment: _In Britain we could say: Twice four years_...we could say that but I suspect that most would say "Two four-year terms" as suggested in a comment on the question.

Comment: True, but that's rephrasing. I was considering the way the OP phrased it. :) We might more
 colloqually say 'four years twice'.